# What is the limit for the "New" column on Kanban board?

Tags: azure-devops

The Kanban board for backlog items seems to have a limit based on the order (position) of a card in the backlog. This may be related to the WIP limit, but this cannot be changed for the "new" column.

What is this limit? I find that once I go to the backlog and move an item to a position close to the top like position 10, then it appears on the Kanban board. But when it is in position 100 for example, it does not appear on the board.

Answer (score 0):

For the **order** of WIT in kanban board, it’s ordered by the created time or WIT ID (from old to new, but if you created WIT from Kanban board, the new created WIT will list on top). And you can reorder it via dragging a WIT up or down.

For the concept of **WIP limits** (Work in Progress limits), you can refer details in [Work in Progress limits](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/kanban/wip-limits).

> An essential Kanban practice─Work in Progress limits, aka “WIP
>   limits”─constrains the amount of work your team undertakes at each
>   work stage. It's designed to focus your team on completing items
>   before starting new work. While counter-intuitive at first, many teams
>   find WIP limits helps them increase their productivity and improve
>   their software quality.

And the New status is not the process for a WIT, or you can treat the New status means the work has not be started. So there is no need to set limit for it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one. When your backlog is long, the new column on the Kanban board shows a limited amount of cards and displays a link that says "find more items online". When you click it, more cards show. I assume this is designed this way for optimization to prevents hundreds of cards from displaying. The name is just misleading as I am already "online".